# What can we use just target win ie7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

We can target both ie6 & ie7 with the * hack.

Is there a way to target ie7 only, just like you can target ie6 with the underscore hack?

Answer (score 1):

Use [conditional stylesheets](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) instead of css hacking.

Example:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
This is only read by IE7 and lower. Include specific css here.
<![endif]-->
```

If you insist on using css hacks (which you should not), take a [look here](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks)

Taken from [this source](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks) (credits to webdevout.net)

IE 7 only: `*:first-child+html {}`

Comment: sorry ,i think it's too complex ,is there any simple way? like "*" just a single word

Comment: I editted my answer to include a hack. But try and give the conditional comments a try. It's not complex. You simply include a specific css file for ie7 which you edit without any prefixes or hacks...

Comment: @timezhong: Seriously? That's complex? I can't think of anything simpler than that.

Comment: @PetrMarek why is `:first-child` necessary?

Comment: @Knu It's to hide the styles from IE6. I successfully avoid using css hacks tho.

Comment: @PetrMarek IE6 doesn't support `+` anyway. Just found out [why](http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/css/filters/star-plus-html/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if ie 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-for-ie7-only.css" /><![endif]-->
```